# Bootstrap navbar-toggle won't automatically populate

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for the first time, and have seen examples online about toggle menus being able to automatically populate themselves with all the links in the non-toggle version. I attempted to do this below but for some reason mine doesn't seem to work.

I've also looked all over but cannot find any answers on other posts or websites that can help me.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="navi nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdowni dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdowni dropdown-toggle" id="nobackground" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdowni dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#"><li>Option 1-1</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Option 1-2</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Option 1-3</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Option 1-4</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Option 1-5</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="grey">//</li>
                <li><a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                <li id="grey">//</li>
                <li><a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                <li id="grey">//</li>
                <li><a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I'm sorry if my code is messy - I've not done much web development before. I'm guessing it's to do with some ordering of the `<li>` and `<a>` tags, but I could not work it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I have done, unfortunately it was of no help to me - maybe I just didn't understand it though

Comment: did you include `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: @fierynot, have you included the bootstrap css and javascript? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Yes I have, both of them, in the correct order with JQuery before the bootstrap js

Comment: Well, trying it in a Bootstrap environment (http://www.bootply.com/YOJNaW6MTK) it is working like it should. Please review the rest of your HTML and check if you are including the right sources. Also check the console for any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your code is working perfectly just see the preview here. [see the output](https://plnkr.co/edit/rMpdNzl5Ck9BpJObnOBt?p=preview)
I have only added a navbar-default class in  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" /> </head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="navi nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdowni dropdown"> <a class="dropdowni dropdown-toggle" id="nobackground" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 1</a>
                        <ul class="dropdowni dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#">
                                <li>Option 1-1</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <li>Option 1-2</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <li>Option 1-3</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <li>Option 1-4</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <li>Option 1-5</li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="grey">//</li>
                    <li> <a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 2</a> </li>
                    <li id="grey">//</li>
                    <li> <a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 3</a> </li>
                    <li id="grey">//</li>
                    <li> <a id="nobackground" href="#">Option 4</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, it is working! It must be my "navi" css class for some reason - when I removed that it works but is poorly formatted. Thank you again!